# Windows does not recognise GPU and NVIDIA driver refuses to install

Tags: windows-8, drivers

After reinstalling Windows (moving from 7 to 8) on a Dell Dimension E520, Windows does not recognise the GPU. It's a GeForce 7300 LE.

The hardware IDs listed in the device manager are:

- `PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_71A7&SUBSYS_01871043&REV_00`
- `PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_71A7&SUBSYS_01871043`
- `PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_71A7&CC_038000`
- `PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_71A7&CC_0380`

The device instance path listed in the device manager is: `PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_71A7&SUBSYS_01871043&REV_00\4&3886766A&0&0108`

According to [this PCI database](http://www.pcidatabase.com/search.php?device_search_str=71A7&device_search=Search), it's detected as an *ATI RADEON X1300/X1550 Series Secondary*.

I've downloaded the 307.83 driver for Windows 7 32-bit, which is the latest version with support for this card. There are no Windows 8 drivers available but these should work from what I've read, the system is Windows 8.1 32-bit. It refuses to install and displays this message:

> This graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware

I've tried modifying `C:\NVIDIA\DisplayDriver\307.83\Win8_WinVista_Win7\International\Display.Driver\nv_dispi.inf` (the only `.inf` file in that directory) to append lines after the original lines for this card, as recommended by various pages on the internet:

```
%NVIDIA_DEV.01D1%           = Section001, PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_01D1                 
%NVIDIA_DEV.01D1.01%           = Section001, PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_71A7&SUBSYS_01871043&REV_00\4&3886766A&0&0108
...
NVIDIA_DEV.01D1 = "NVIDIA GeForce 7300 LE"
NVIDIA_DEV.01D1.01 = "NVIDIA GeForce 7300 LE - modified INF"
```

Sadly, this did not help. What can I do at this point?

Comment: I would start with a complete uninstall of the existing drivers. Video drivers can be tough to remove. I recall having a heck of a lot of problems a few years back. I ended up buying a utility to completely remove it because I could not purge it from my system. Maybe something like [How to Uninstall Drivers in Windows](http://www.pcworld.com/article/246041/how_to_uninstall_drivers_in_windows.html) or [Download Display Driver Uninstaller DDU](http://www.guru3d.com/files-details/display-driver-uninstaller-download.html) would help.

Comment: "There are no Windows 8 drivers available but these should work from what I've read" considering the WDM version was changed between Windows 7 and Windows 8 I don't see how this could be the case.  **It should be easy enough to verify visual what card you have.**  I should add databases like you linked to are only as good as the person who entered the data.

Comment: @Ramhound as I understand it, drivers for previous WDM versions work on newer OSes, they just can't use new features. In fact I've just installed the Vista driver for the card (which isn't the one I thought it was, see comment on the answer) and they work fine.

Comment: @Stijn - I can say without a shadow of a doubt that your asking for trouble if you try using  previous versions of the WDM on a newer version of Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound I'm sure that Windows wouldn't allow me to install and use the driver if that were the case. Also, quoting [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Driver_Model): *"WDM drivers are designed to be forward-compatible so that a WDM driver can run on a version of Windows newer than what the driver was initially written for, but doing that would mean that the driver cannot take advantage of any new features introduced with the new version. WDM is generally not backward-compatible, that is, a WDM driver is not guaranteed to run on any older version of Windows."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are your hardware IDs, then you definitely do **not** have a GeForce 7300 LE.  You have a AMD/ATI Radeon X1000 series.

Most likely there's no support for this on Windows 8.  Your best chance is the [Vista 32-bit driver from Dell](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=6DM6P).  If the installer fails, try extracting the contents and using the Device Manager to install it manually by browsing to the location you extracted to.

Comment: So I'm not the only one that noticed that the hardware ID and alleged card are mismatched...

Comment: I've pulled out the card, and surprisingly it is indeed a Radeon X1300 series. Apparently the original card was replaced at some point, I'm no longer using the system myself and wasn't aware of this.

Comment: I've downloaded the drivers from http://www.asus.com/Graphics_Cards/EAX1300TD128M/HelpDesk_Download/ and they work fine, by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Dell Dimension E520 specs](http://www.pcworld.com/product/29435/dimension-e520-desktop-customizable.html), your video card is Nvidia GeForce 6150 LE.

According to the Nvidia support website, the correct driver for that card is [GeForce 307.74](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/56377/en-us),
and (just in case) the same driver also supports the GeForce 7300 LE.

I suggest to download and install that driver, using the installation option that erases any existing
installation, then reboot. If that doesn't work, go into the Device Manager and delete the display
device, then reboot.

If nothing works, please go into the Device Manager, open the branches of "Display adapters" and
that of "Monitors" and add a screenshot of it to your post.

Comment: As is the case with many Dells, the Dimension E520 is available with many different configurations, including different video cards.  Your PC World link is just one particular configuration.

Comment: @Jason: The above driver covers all models of GeForce series 6 and 7, so I believe it's worthwhile trying it out. If the display in the Device Manager is correct for the card type, one can download from the [AMD Graphics Drivers and Software page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download) the auto detect utility to verify if it's truly an AMD card and install the driver. The rest of the procedure is as outlined above.

Comment: I've pulled out the card, and surprisingly it is indeed a Radeon X1300 series. Apparently the original card was replaced at some point, I'm no longer using the system myself and wasn't aware of this. The original card was a 7300 though, as noted by @Jason there are multiple configurations for Dells.

Comment: It should be a simple matter to find the right driver, as in my comment above. Once it's installed, Windows should recognize the device (reboot might be required). If it doesn't, then you do indeed have a difficult problem to analyze (but we are not there yet).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, my recommendation for you is to download [Driver Fusion](http://treexy.com/products/driver-fusion/download) and wipe out any remnants of your old drivers of this card (just in case).
*IMO it's almost a MUST software for situation like yours.*

After that, Please try to use [this driver](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/56377/en-us) instead.
As nvidia noted, 307.74 it's the latest driver who should work with windows 8 (though you have 8.1 which is different, so it might not work as well).

Comment: You don't need third-party software to uninstall a driver.  Just uninstall it through the control panel, if you are really paranoid, delete the device and the driver from device manager.

Comment: @Ramhound You can never get all the leftovers from the control panel alone. And it doesn't recommend to delete anything from device manager.

Comment: I do not trust software like `Driver Fusion` and I can guarantee you that removing the `Nvidia` software through the `Control Panel` removes the drivers.

Comment: @Ramhound Let's not make make it too personal, You can do whatever you like to uninstall *your drivers*, If you have any specific reason why you don't trust Driver Fusion you can share it here, Or even make your own answer.
Other than that, please remember there it most of the time more than one ways to solve this kind of problems.

Comment: There's nothing to wipe out, there's no driver installed right now, except for a generic driver by Windows I suppose. I've pulled out the card, and surprisingly it is indeed a Radeon X1300 series. Apparently the original card was replaced at some point, I'm no longer using the system myself and wasn't aware of this.

Comment: @Stijn Well, at least you know why it didn't work.